# System.Directory.getDirectoryContents unicode support

Tags: haskell, unicode, ghc

The following code prints something like `°Ð½Ð´Ð¸Ñ-ÐÑÐ¿Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ`

```
getDirectoryContents "path/to/directory/that/contains/files/with/nonASCII/names"
  >>= mapM_ putStrLn
```

Looks like it is a ghc [bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3307) and it is fixed already in repository. But what to do until everybody upgrade ghc?

The last time I encountered such the problem (it was few years ago, btw), I used utf8-string package to convert strings, but I don't remember how I did it, and ghc unicode support was changed visibly last years.

So, what is the best (or at least working) way to get directory contents with full unicode support?

ghc version 7.0.4
locale en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple workaround using [`decodeString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/utf8-string/0.3.6/doc/html/Codec-Binary-UTF8-String.html#v:decodeString) and [`encodeString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/utf8-string/0.3.6/doc/html/Codec-Binary-UTF8-String.html#v:encodeString) from [utf8-string](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string).

```
import System.Directory
import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as UTF8

main = do
   getDirectoryContents "." >>= mapM_ (putStrLn . UTF8.decodeString)
   putStrLn "------------"
   readFile (UTF8.encodeString "brøken-file-nåme.txt") >>= putStrLn
```

Output:

```
.
..
brøken-file-nåme.txt
Broken.hs
------------
hello
```

Comment: @Yuras: As I understood it, `base` will to the UTF8 conversion itself, so you might want to use conditional compilation to remove the conversion if using the appropriate version of `base`.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at [system-filepath](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath), which provides an abstract datatype for representing filepaths. I've used it extensively for some internal code and it works wonderfully.

Comment: thanks. it's like `fixName = encodeString . fromText . T.pack`