# Prelude.writeFile with a Chinese file name

Tags: haskell, unicode, cjk, writefile

I'm testing something that like to output content to file, which has a Chinese name.

The file would be created successfully with right content but not file name.

I take a look at the function `writeFile`[^1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.0.0/System-IO.html) and it represents file name using `String`.
So I suspect this might be root cause.

```haskell
    file :: FilePath
    file = "上海万达影城.html"

    content :: String
    content = "<h1>hello</h1>"

    write2File :: IO ()
    write2File = writeFile file content
```

Thanks your help!

-Simon

--------------------- Updated

1. GHC at my side is 7.0.2
2. A workaround found before upgrade. see detail below and the code change like

   ```haskell
   import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as UTF8
   file = UTF8.encodeString "上海万达影城.html"
   ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412577/haskell-char-unicode-and-turkish

Comment: Works here with ghc-7.4.1 what compiler version and OS have you?

Comment: @Daniel, I'm working at ghc-7.0.2 actually thus I think I'll firstly try solution mentioned by Dietrich Epp.

Comment: Yep, upgrading is the proper course of action then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String is a list of unicode code points in Haskell. The interpretation of that list of unicode code points is system dependent. (You also need a not too old GHC to support this).

Generally though, once you're locale is set correctly, things just work.

---

N.B. there have been caveats in the past -- e.g. the old bug: [System.Directory.getDirectoryContents unicode support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806686/system-directory-getdirectorycontents-unicode-support) - which might involve workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, you can use the `System.Posix.IO.ByteString` module.  This will let you specify file paths as byte strings, so you can do the encoding/decoding yourself.

This is a known bug, and was fixed in 7.2.1.

http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3307

Comment: Seems unix-2.5.* package has `System.Posix.IO.ByteString` but I'm working on unix-2.4. I'll verify it again after I got chance to upgrade GHC. Thanks Dietrich.